# I want to scp one or more file to different directories in another computer

Tags: scp

I want to `scp` several files from one computer to other.

The command are:

```
scp -r file1 file2 com2@ip:dir1
scp file1 file2 com2@ip:dir2
```

How can I

```
scp -r file1 file2 file1 file2 to Dir1 & Dir3
```

on other computer or is there any other command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but I would recommend `rsync` instead of `scp` (both will work, `rsync` just enjoys more current development than `scp`). When copying multiple source files, if they are not the only files in a directory, you can use wildcards with `rsync` to perform the transfer. In your case you will have to invoke `rsync` twice to copy to both `Dir1` and `Dir3` as the destination (otherwise the destination is ambiguous -- it is the same for `scp`):

```
rsync -uv file** user@ip:/Dir1
rsync -uv file** user@ip:/Dir3
```

**Note:** you can substitute `host.domain.tld` for `ip` above. Also note that wildcards with `rsync` are not the same as your normal wildcards used with your shell. You normally must provide a double `**` for `rsync` to treat it as a wildcard.

With `scp` you can use your normal shell wildcards and other brace and character expansion for the transfer which can help you narrow the files to transfer:

```
scp file[12] user@ip:/Dir1
scp file[12] user@ip:/Dir3
```

To transfer only `file1` and `file2` to `Dir1` and `Dir3` at the remote `ip`.